# Replace is not replacing the text

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check whether values of a model have been changed, so that I can warn the user that he/she has unsaved changes.

```
modelHasChanged(): boolean {
 let search1 = ",\"_$visited\":true";
 let search2 = "\"_$visited\":true";

 let strModel = JSON.stringify(this.model);
 strModel = strModel.replace(/search1/g, "");
 strModel = strModel.replace(/search2/g, "");

 let o = JSON.stringify(new MyNewObject());
 let diff = strModel !== o;
 return diff;
}
```

Unfortunately, it's always true. When I hover over `strModel`, I noticed that even when I don't do anything, `,"_$visited":true` is being added anyway for some properties. For instance:

```
o = "{"proprty1": null, "property2": {} }"
strModel = "{"proprty1": null, "property2": {"_$visited":true} }"
```

Therefore, If I can remove those added texts then the comparison will work. `Replace` is not working. I'm still getting the original text.

```
strModel = strModel.replace(/search1/g, "");
strModel = strModel.replace(/search2/g, "");
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: instead of stringifying and using RegExp is there a reason you can't just check the object? Is this being stored or something?

Comment: I suspect what you're seeing may be a console artifact, it's not actually in the object.

Comment: Do you see it if you do `console.log(strModel)` rather than hover over the variable?

Comment: I think this would be a bit easier to help out with if you could provide a snippet or at least some code showing the model being worked on by your function. As is, aside from what @Barmar suggested, the example doesn't really provide a whole lot of information.

Comment: you have to put the value in the regex, not the variable name.

Comment: @zfrisch what do you mean by checking the object, comparing properties one by one?

Comment: @DanielA.White can you please show what you mean?

Comment: it looks like you want to remove `$visited`. just do that in the `/yourPatternHere/`, not like `/search2/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to escape characters like { , }, _.

Try below code on javascript console. seems to work.

```
let temp = "{\"property1\": null. \"property2\": {} }"
let strModel = "{\"property1\": null, \"property2\": {\"_$visited\":true} }"
strModel = strModel.replace(/\{\"\_\$visited\":true\}/, "{}");
```

Comment: Your code is working on the console. The only problem is that this is how `strModel` is being built `let strModel = JSON.stringify(this.model);`. I don't know if I need to escape every `"`.

Comment: Yes, you need to escape all special characters.

Comment: To search special characters, like [ \ ^ $ . | ? * + ( ) literally, we need to prepend them with \ (“escape them”).